# Calcuations on column combinations in a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, array-broadcasting

Supposing that I have the following `numpy` array / `pandas` df:

```
| 0  | 1  | 2  | 3  | 4  | 5  | 6  |
| -- | -- | -- | -- | -- | -- | -- |
| 39 | 27 | 36 | 30 | 32 | 29 | 40 |
| 36 | 26 | 32 | 37 | 30 | 40 | 28 |
| 32 | 40 | 35 | 30 | 28 | 39 | 31 |
| 27 | 34 | 28 | 28 | 31 | 35 | 40 |
| 36 | 29 | 26 | 26 | 25 | 39 | 33 |
| 39 | 30 | 26 | 29 | 38 | 40 | 37 |
| 31 | 28 | 30 | 37 | 29 | 38 | 32 |
| 26 | 39 | 34 | 40 | 35 | 25 | 36 |
| 35 | 38 | 31 | 38 | 40 | 28 | 39 |
| 25 | 35 | 40 | 27 | 27 | 30 | 27 |
| 32 | 30 | 31 | 35 | 38 | 25 | 32 |
| 30 | 38 | 35 | 36 | 30 | 37 | 34 |
| 33 | 31 | 36 | 32 | 30 | 25 | 25 |
| 36 | 31 | 30 | 38 | 39 | 30 | 38 |
| 25 | 29 | 31 | 30 | 27 | 36 | 38 |
```

I want to run `f(coli,colj)` on each column pair so `f(0,1), f(0,2), f(0,6), ..., f(6,6)` and acheive a 6x6 array. I was able to acheive this realtively fast using a nested loop which is ok. The problem I have ran into is that I also need to compare the outcome of `f(coli,colj)` with itself so `g(f(i,j), f(k,m))` which produces a 6x6x6x6 array. A 4D  nested loops takes about a minute to run .

```
for i in array.T:
    for j in array.T:
        for k in array.T:
            for m in array.T:
                output[i][j][k][l] = g(f(i, j), f(k, m))
```

Is there a faster way with broadcasting?

To rephrase the question, how would you perform a certain function by choosing all possible pairs from the column to create a 2D array and then choose all the pairs again from that array and repeat the same process. Hope that make sense

Comment: Could you add a small example with input and output of what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> To rephrase the question, how would you perform a certain function by choosing all possible pairs from the column to create a 2D array..

Assuming you have a dataframe `df` with shape `(n, m)`, ie:

```
n, m = df.shape
```

Use np.mgrid to create indices (i, j) of all pairs of columns:

```
i, j = np.mgrid[:m, :m].reshape((2, -1))
```

(i and j now both have shape `(m**2,)`)

..and then index your dataframe using i and j for each arg to f respectively:

```
f_res = f(df.iloc[:, i], df.iloc[:, j])
```

(f_res now has shape `(n, m**2)`)

Now you can repeat the same but on "f_res" for the args to g:

```
i, j = np.mgrid[:m**2, :m**2].reshape((2, -1))
```

(i and j now both have shape (m**4,)

```
g_res = g(f_res.iloc[:, i], f_res.iloc[:, j])
```

(g_res now has shape `(n, m**4)`)

If you want the result of f(.., ..) shaped `(n, m, m)` then do:

```
f_res_grid = f_res.values.reshape((-1, m, m))
```

And if you want the result of g(.., ..) shaped `(n, m, m, m, m)` then do likewise:

```
g_res_grid = g_res.values.reshape((n, m, m, m, m))
```

I hope you get the idea..

Comment: Even faster on numpy!

Comment: My nested 2D loop was running at 25 ms - with that is 12 ms!! I am gonna run the 4D now - should be good!

Comment: @RebeccaKennedy I'm glad I could help.

Comment: 1.2 seconds which isn't bad at all! There is lots of redudant combinations which I can get rid of and that will hopefully improve things a bit more. Many thanks!